# Алгоритмическая задача на питоне, как улучшить код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, циклы

Всем привет! Недавно изучаю алгоритмические задачи на питоне, сделал одну задачу, хотел бы узнать, как её можно улучшить? (можно побольше объяснений).

**Гоша и Тимофей нашли необычный тренажёр для скоростной печати и хотят освоить его. Тренажёр представляет собой поле из клавиш 4×4, в котором на каждом раунде появляется конфигурация цифр и точек. На клавише написана либо точка, либо цифра от 1 до 9. В момент времени t игрок должен одновременно нажать на все клавиши, на которых написана цифра t. Гоша и Тимофей могут нажать в один момент времени на k клавиш каждый. Если в момент времени t были нажаты все нужные клавиши, то игроки получают 1 балл.
Найдите число баллов, которое смогут заработать Гоша и Тимофей, если будут нажимать на клавиши вдвоём.**

**Формат ввода**

В первой строке дано целое число k (1 ≤ k ≤ 5).
В четырёх следующих строках задан вид тренажёра –— по 4 символа в каждой строке. Каждый символ —– либо точка, либо цифра от 1 до 9. Символы одной строки идут подряд и не разделены пробелами.

**Формат вывода**

Выведите единственное число –— максимальное количество баллов, которое смогут набрать Гоша и Тимофей.

**Пример 1:**

*Ввод:*

```
3
1231
2..2
2..2
2..2
```

*Вывод:*

```
2
```

**Пример 2:**

*Ввод:*

```
4
1111
9999
1111
9911
```

*Вывод:*

```
1
```

**Пример 3:**

*Ввод:*

```
4
1111
1111
1111
1111
```

*Вывод:*

```
0
```

Ограничение времени - 1 секунда | Ограничение памяти - 64mb

Мой вариант:

```
k = int(input()) * 2 #Эти 2 части перенести в if __name__ == "__main__"  и сделать def "snake_case"
matrix = []
for i in range(4):
    numbers = input()
    matrix += numbers
t = 1
score = 0
while t <= 9:
    count_t = matrix.count(str(t))
    if 0 < count_t <= k:
        score += 1 #Тут была идея сделать функцию sum() с условием, чтобы избавиться от лишних строк, но не знаю, нужно это или нет
    t += 1
print(score)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. А что за переменная t.И почему ее нет в входных данных?

Comment: **либо цифра от 1 до 9**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше решение нормальное. Единственное плохое место: `matrix += numbers`. Этот оператор копирует список раз за разом, что может привести к тормозам. Но здесь всего четыре итерации. Замедление не будет заметно.

Решение можно доработать в сторону большей питоничности.

1. Другой ввод символов из матрицы.
2. `collections.Counter` - специальный словарь для подсчёта символов в матрице.
3. Итерация по словарю. Обрабатываем только те цифры, которые есть в матрице.
4. Суммирование с помощью `sum` вместо `score += 1`.

Код:

```
import collections

k = int(input()) * 2
print(sum(                                      # 4
    1                                           # 4
    for key, v in collections.Counter(          # 2  
        c for _ in range(4) for c in input()    # 1
    ).items()                                   # 3
    if key.isdigit() and v <= k
))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
count_t = matrix.count(str(t))
```

Вы прогоняете свой список 9 раз. Лучше сделать так:

```
nums = '12456789'
col_vo = {'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':0, '5':0, '6':0, '7':0, '8':0, '9':0}
for i in matrix:
    if i in nums:
        col_vo[i] += 1
```

Вы получаете словарь со всеми цифрами(ключи) и кол-во вхождениями их в список(значения).

Comment: Вы изобрели `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже учусь, и хотел бы поделиться своим решением. Не знаю на сколько оно затратное будет по времени и памяти.

```
def sleight_of_hand(matrix):
    # промежуток времени от 1 до 9
    time = range(1, 10)
    numerate = []
    for v in time:
        count = matrix.count(str(v))
        numerate.append(count)
    points = sum(1 for x in numerate if hands >= x and x != 0)
    return points


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hands = int(input())*2
    matrix = ''
    matrix = ''.join([matrix + input() for i in range(4)])
    print(sleight_of_hand(matrix))
```

Ниже второй вариант кода. В обоих случаях мне сказали можно его более оптимизировать.

```
def sleight_of_hand(matrix):
    # промежуток времени от 1 до 9
    time = range(1, 10)
    points = 0
    for v in time:
        count = matrix.count(str(v))
        if hands >= count and count != 0:
            points += 1
    return points


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hands = int(input())*2
    matrix = ''
    matrix = ''.join([matrix + input() for i in range(4)])
    print(sleight_of_hand(matrix))
```